# how can i round up nearest 10 using rdlc report c#

Tags: c#

=Round(56,10)
//iwant to be 60[enter link description here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1868215.aspx?Round%20Off%20To%20Nearest%2010%20in%20RDLC)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/round-the-given-number-to-nearest-multiple-of-10/

Answer (score 1):

I'm truthfully not terribly familiar with RDLC Reports, but in "pure" C# you can just divide by `10.0`, round up, and multiply by 10:

```
Math.Ceiling(56 / 10.0) * 10
```

because `56 / 10.0 = 5.6`, `Math.Ceiling(5.6) = 6`, and `6 * 10 = 60`.

Note that it's actually important that you divide by `10.0` (rather than `10`) so that the compiler "knows" that you're doing floating-point division (rather than integer division).

Hopefully this'll get you started in the right direction.